# Sending arguments to a function without parameters

Tags: c

If I have a function

```
int foo() {
  /* stuff */
}
```

to which I want to send arguments (in spite the fact that it's a bad practice):

```
int main(void) {
    int arg1 = 3;
    int arg2 = 4;
    foo(arg1, arg2);
    return 0;
}
```

then, how can I refer to the arguments `arg1` and `arg2` inside `foo()`?

Comment: atleast define default arguments. And I dont understand the background. Why would you wanna do this??

Comment: It's not "bad practice". It's not C. Bad practice is if you claim to be a dentist but pull out the wrong tooth. What you're doing is amputating a leg instead.

Comment: You cannot. Because you did not receive them in any argument variables.

Comment: you should be thankful if this code does not crash

Comment: you need to set arg1 and arg2 as globals. Which is not a good idea though.

Comment: Yes it is. It compiles under gcc.

Comment: Turn on all the warnings and listen to them. Use `-W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` at least.

Comment: Why are you doning this?

Comment: If you figure out the calling conventions on your platform you could
probably access local variables in the calling stack frame from a called function. It would not be portable and it may break depending on the compiler optimizations performed, but it is possible.

Comment: @PerEkman: indeed. Although you'd need to get hold of the stack/frame pointer first...

Comment: @LeifEricson: not everything that compiles is valid C (especially without warning flags)...

Comment: I don't understand the downvoting. I am aware of the fact that this is an ugly hack, but I don't see the problem of having an academic discussion about whether it is possible or not, and how.

Comment: @LeifEricson: I suspect it's because this isn't a question about a practical programming problem (although I didn't down vote).

Comment: It is `int foo()`, not `int foo(void)`. So the number of expected arguments is not 0, it is unspecified. Thus the call is perfectly valid, but senseless, because there is no way to get the data.

Comment: The most interesting question, standards-wise, is: _why does the compiler not warn about this_ (using `&` on function arguments) ? Neither gcc, clang/llvm nor Intel ICC warn (with any command line flags I've found). The code generated is not doing the intended thing on 64bit x86, that's for sure.

Comment: @FrankH. — what is the problem with applying `&` to a variable that happens to be function argument?  There is a memory location where the variable is stored; if you take the address of the variable, the compiler can't keep it in a register, but that's the compiler's problem, not the standard's problem.  It is perfectly legal.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler in architectures (such as x86_64) where function arguments are _passed in registers_ there is no memory location where function arguments are stored. If you apply `&` to an argument, you force the compiler to "auto-vivify" a _temporary local variable_ (by copying). You'll never have an "outer" scope that way, so if that's the intended thing, no you cannot get it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not exactly what you want and is completely unportable but it illustrates
the principle. You probably have to adjust the offsets and the offsets will be different if the calling function (main in this case) has other variables on the stack.
And of course, if the target platform has a stack that grows in the other direction you'd have to change the loop to count down p instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(void) {
        int *p;
        int a, b;
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
                p = (&i + i);
                printf("i %d : p %p %d\n", i, p, *p);
        }
        a = *(&i + 11);
        b = *(&i + 10);
        printf("a %d\n", a);
        printf("b %d\n", b);
        return a + b;
}

int main(void) {
        int a = 8;
        int b = 2;

        foo();
        return 0;
}
```

And for the record, this kind of stuff is both fun and useful. In particular, it can be invaluable to know when debugging. So I think the question is a good one. That does not mean that this kind of thing should ever end up in any "production" code.

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with `int foo(int arg1, int arg2);`?

If you're unsure about the number of arguments you will be passing look into [variadic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Example_in_C).

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by having a global state and a helper function:

```
static int foo_i, foo_j;
static void foo_setup(int i, int j) {
    foo_i = i; foo_j = j;
}

int foo() {
    return foo_i % foo_j;
}


int main() {
    foo_setup(10,40);
    printf("%d\n", foo());
}
```

To decide whether this is suitable for you, you must consider that this solution is non-reentrant. If you are using threads, you may need to synchronise the calls to foo_setup and foo. Similarly, if you will not call foo immediately after calling foo_setup, you need to carefully craft your code to not use code calling foo_setup, in between.

If you can use c++, you can pass the arguments through the constructor and define an `operator()` method for the struct.

Comment: "If you can use c++, ..." yes. And if you can use Python, there is a solution as well.

Comment: And for Perl...
`sub foo { my $var = shift; print $var,"\n"; } foo('test');`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestions. The solution I suggest for the problem I introduced is as follows:

```
static int helper(int argc, ...) {
  unsigned *argv = (unsigned *) (void *)(&argc + 1);

  switch (argc) {
  case 0: /* do stuff */ 
  case 1: /* do stuff with argv[0] */
  case 2: /* do stuff with argv[0], argv[1] */
  ...
  case n: /* do stuff with argv[0], argv[1], ..., argv[n] */
  }
}

int goo(void) {
  return helper(0);
}

int bar(int arg1) {
  return helper(1, arg1);
}

int foo(int arg1, int arg2) {
  return helper(2, arg1, arg2);
}

int main(void) {
  int arg1 = 3;
  int arg2 = 4;
  return foo(arg1, arg2);
}
```

Comment: Why is this better than just putting the appropriate code inside of the `foo`, `bar`, and `goo` methods?

Comment: Because goo, bar, and foo have too much identical code. http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=jznqWsCu

Comment: This creates incorrect / not-working code if you're on non-stack-based architectures. Interestingly, there seems nothing that stops you from using address-of (`&`) on a function argument even though the results of that might be meaningless (args passed in registers do not have addresses).

Comment: @LeifEricson so, after all, the question wasn't about declaring no arguments in the function declaration? (`int helper(int argc,...)`) in that case, you should definitely use `va_list`, `va_start` instead of `(void*)&argc+1`